# send data form hybrid android app to simple website in google app engine using json

Tags: android, json, google-app-engine, jquery, hybrid

i have a hybrid android app build with html5 and javascript , and i want to send data using json ajax jquery to a web site in google app engine .
can you please give me any tutoriel to do that .

the function 'go' that i used in my hybrid android file.js app when i click on a button is :

```
    function go() {


            $.getJSON('website.com', {

        }).done(function( data ) {

            $.each(data, function (key, field) {
               alert(key + " : " + field);
            });
        });  
            return false;
}
```

now. i want to get a simple data from the url above which will be a website deployed in google app engine ... i don't know how to do it .

please any tutorials ..

Comment: is the android app hosted on the same google app engine app?

Comment: no. only the website who's hosted in the google app engine .. i must make some http request json in the android and send data with it in the datasotr of the website in GAE..

Comment: have you look at jquery's jsonp? its a kind of hack on how to do crossplatform js injection but built-in to jquery's $.ajax data type jsonp.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Google App Engine endpoints:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/

This makes it easy to create app engine apps for Android developers.

Comment: question is about hybrid, not native android.